# Unity3d: handle spaces in file names

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, create-directory

How do I open/create the files having spaces in their name? I have the following piece of code:

```
FILENAME = (GameInfo.gameTitle.ToString() + " - " + month + "-" + day + "-" + year + "-" + hour + "-" + minute + "-" + second);
        // The dump file holds all the emotion measurements for each frame. Put in a separate file to not clog other data.
        DUMPNAME = FILENAME + "-EMOTION-DUMP.txt";
        FILENAME += ".txt";

        Debug.Log("FILENAME==== " + FILENAME);
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(FILENAME);
        file.Directory.Create(); // If it already exists, this call does nothing, so no fear.
```

Here `GameInfo.gameTitle.ToString()` returns "Some game name" and the resulting file name is thus "Some: game name - 2-12-2018-23-14-10.txt". On executing this piece of code, a new folder with the name "Some" is created instead of a new text file with name "Some game name - 2-12-2018-23-14-10.txt". How do I escape the spaces in the file name?
I tried using `WWW.EscapeURL` and it works, but it appends weird % characters in between as expected. Is there a better solution to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to create a `FileInfo`, use

```
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("./"+FILENAME); // with a fixed file name
```

The `:` inside your files name is confusing the create command. There are several characters that are forbidden inside Filenames which you should remove before trying to save that:

```
var forbidden = new char[] { '/', '\\', '?', '*', ':', '<', '>', '|', '\"' };
```

Or better use [Path.GetInvalidPathChars()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidpathchars(v=vs.110).aspx) but beware of

> The array returned from this method is not guaranteed to contain the *complete set* of characters that are invalid in file and directory names. The full set of invalid characters **can vary by file system**. For example, on Windows-based desktop platforms, invalid path characters might include ASCII/Unicode characters 1 through 31, as well as quote ("), less than (<), greater than (>), pipe (|), backspace (\b), null (\0) and tab (\t).

You can try this:

```
static string FixFileName (string fn)
{
  var forbidden = new char[] { '/', '\\', '?', '*', ':', '<', '>', '|', '\"' };

  var sb = new StringBuilder (fn);    
  for (int i = 0; i < sb.Length; i++)
  {
    if ((int)sb[i] < 32 || forbidden.Contains (sb[i]))
      sb[i] = '-';
  }

  return sb.ToString ().Trim();
}
```